# How can I LIMIT on various WHERE clauses in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause

Let's say I have the following MySQL table:

```
id | species
------------
1  | dog
2  | dog
3  | dog
4  | cat
5  | cat
6  | fish
7  | fish
8  | fish
```

I want to get the ids of 2 dogs, 1 cat, and 1 fish (they don't have to be in order). For example, {1, 2, 4, 6} would be a valid output.

Is there a way to do this in one SQL query? As far as I know, LIMIT is a fairly simple operator that can't do this. Maybe WHERE can be manipulated? Or would multiple SQL queries be the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I know the best you can do is to use [`UNION`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html) to combine the results of three `SELECT`s, e.g.:

```
SELECT id, species FROM animals
  WHERE species = 'dog'
  LIMIT 2
UNION
SELECT id, species FROM animals
  WHERE species = 'cat'
  LIMIT 1
UNION
SELECT id, species FROM animals
  WHERE species = 'fish'
  LIMIT 1;

# Producing:
#
# id | species
# ---+--------
#  1 | dog
#  2 | dog
#  4 | cat
#  6 | fish
```